# incrementally download the data from all the tables in a specific project in sqoop?

Tags: sqoop

Increment download of single table command:

```
sqoop --import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/db --username root
--password cloudera --table employ -m1 --incremental append  --check-column id --last-value 6
```

I don't know how to incrementally download all tables data.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop provides incremental import mode only for single table. You can use use `import-all-tables` command with `--exclude-tables <tables>` options for `<tables>` which will be incrementally import with usual `import`.

Comment: but the  --check-column and --last-value are different for multiples tables. so how to download multiple table data using this. any other method